# Regex to select records from a db matching a predefined text prefix

Tags: php, sql, regex

I need to grab all records from a database table where the values in the option_name column begins with the prefix 'my_'

And store the results of that query in an array consisting of option_name, option_value pairs?

The database columns I need are called "option_name" and "option_value".

I'll use this array to execute some further processing in a for loop.

I'm guessing this would require a regex in the SQL statement for the records where the option_name values match the target prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the SQL part, just use `like` with the % wildcard:

```
select * from YourTable where option_name like 'my|_%' escape '|'
```

Since `_` is also a wildcard you have to escape it.

There's plenty of resources for reading the results of a SQL query in PHP: [here's one](http://progzoo.net/wiki/PHP%3aRead_From_a_Database).

Comment: +1 for getting the little-known `ESCAPE` clause right for portability. Backslash escapes are the default in MySQL, but are not part of the ANSI SQL standard.

Answer (score 2):

If using a simple pattern such as *"begins with"*, you can use the [**`LIKE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator :

```
select *
from your_table
where option_name like 'my\_%';
```

Notes :

- `%` means *"any character, any number of times"*.
- `_` means *"any character, one time"* -- so, if you want **to search for a literal `'_'`, you have to escape it** with a `\`.

Just for information, if you ever need to test for matches with a regex, you'll want to take a look at the [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) section of the manual.

But this is not necessary, here : `like` works fine for *begins with*.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT option_name, option_value FROM table WHERE option_name like 'my_%'");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$array = array("name" => $result['name'],"value" => $result['value']);
}
```